# understanding the slew rate step of implementing gm/id method question

Tags: analog

I am trying to follow method descibed in the article bellow.
we need GBW=100MHz SLEW_Rate=50 V/us Load=1pF
In step "A" they try to find Width of NMOS we have the plots
Gm/Id Vs Id/W, ft vs Gm/Id, gm /gds vs gm/Id  for L = 180 nm

Gm/Id=GBW/SR=12.6 So when we go to Id/W vs Gm/Id plot we get that
Id/W=17.3
Slew rate units is Volts/seconds why they put 50u instead of Id in equation 5?
W=Id/(Id/W)=50u/17.3 \

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334010793_A_GmId_Based_Methodology_for_Designing_Common_Source_Amplifier#fullTextFileContent

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The load capacitance is 1 pF. In order to charge that capacitance at 50 V / microsecond, a current of 50 μA is required (this follows from the branch consitutive equation for a capacitor, viz. \$I = C \frac{dV}{dt}\$. M1 obviously cannot carry less than zero current no matter how hard you cut it off, so the capacitor's charging current is limited to the drain current of M2.

> Slew rate units is Volts/seconds why they put 50u instead of Id in equation 5?

Because 50 μA *is* Id. They know current density and they know the current, so that's how they get the width.

Comment: Hello Nanofarad,A link shows bellow the diagram. The current that goes into the load in not the currect that goes into the Nmosfet. I dont understand how they get the currect that suppose to flow on the mosfet based on slew rate? 
Thanks. ibb.co/6vgpCYN

Comment: Hello Nanofarad,SO we have the load current ,the we need to know the  current that flows on PMOS to know what current flows  on the NMOS.
I_PMOS=I_NMOS+I_Load
How do get the PMOS current then?
 ibb.co/6vgpCYN

Comment: @lub2354 When the NMOS (controlled by the input voltage) is cut off, it carries zero current. Current '2' is zero. All of the PMOS bias current flows into the load. That's the limiting case for the slew rate; you can clearly slew it slower if you wanted to, but that's not what the slew rate spec discusses.

Comment: Hello nanofarad, So if i understand you correctly we assume that all bias current  flows from PMOS to the C_L load.
Our bias on NMOS is not relevant to the slew rate? Thanks.

Comment: @lub2354 The NMOS isn't biased; it's driven by the input signal. The capacitor can be discharged extremely fast by turning the NMOS all the way on until it's nearly a short circuit; the limit is that the capacitor can only be charged at a limited current, which happens to be the PMOS bias current.

Comment: Hello Nanofarad,Why do we look to bias NMOS to get 50uA current threw it too?

Comment: @lub2354 You typically bias it through feedback around the whole circuit; when the output isn't slewing it will end up biased to carry 50 uA of current.

Comment: Hello nanofarad ,So practiccaly speaking, I bias the PMOS assuming the NMOS is cutoff and set it to 50uA .Aferward i connect the NMOS and PMOS with the load and BIAS the NMOS so between NMOS and PMOS there will be 50uA?
I think its not possible.
Both steps are on tottaly different system .I can bias them both together to be 50uA but then when NMOS will be cutoff the current from PMOS might not be 50uA.
What is the logic between those two steps?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't bias the PMOS assuming the NMOS is cut off. You simply bias the PMOS to 50 uA. The NMOS was *only* cut off for the sake of *one calculation*, which was slew rate. The PMOS is driven by a constant Vgs, so it'll be biased to roughly 50 uA (with some small error due to channel length modulation) regardless of whether the NMOS is cut off, itself at 50 uA, or driven hard

Comment: If you cannot see this behavior intuitively, I recommend that you put the system into feedback and simulate it (and then do a second simulation with a large signal input and watch it slew).

Comment: Hello nanofarad,the point is that in the article they say that the drain of the pmos(connection point between NMOS and PMOS ) is at half 1.8V=0.9V
So i bias the Pmos with drain at 0.9V  source at 1.8V?
Correct?
because we need to bias the PMOS at the conditions that is will be in the full system

Comment: @lub2354 yes, that's why I make a remark about channel length modulation. Biasing it while midway is perfectly fine, and you'll always have some variation when your output clips at the rails (as would be the case for *any*) amplifier. The whole point of this technique was a first pass for biasing and sizing, and clearly *no* choice of biasing will work *perfectly* at every point in the voltage range

Comment: ...continuing previous comment, almost every hand calculations design methodology is going to have plenty of approximations and assumptions, and neglecting channel length modulation on the first pass is a fairly reasonable one, because again, if you took CLM you wouldn't be able to pick any one single bias voltage anyway that can cover the whole range.